# Load CSS In Excel

Tags: .net, excel

in .net I have created an excel report which takes a datagrid's render output and puts it into the excel.  The problem I am having is that the CSS classes that are used in the datagrid are not properly displayed because the CSS file is not loaded on the excel document.  Can someone recommend a good way to go around this other than instead of using classes use hard coded style values, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to say that I believe you will have to use inline CSS (no classes/selectors) to make this work.